# Use of Prepared Statements using Concurrency in Java

Tags: java, database, multithreading, concurrency, connection

I have an application that processes lots of data in files and puts this data into a database.  It has been single threaded; so I create a database connection, create prepared statements on that connection, and then reuse these statements while processing the data.  I might process thousands of files and can reuse the same prepared statements over and over but only updating the values.  This has been working great, however ...

It has come to the point where it is taking too long to process the files, and since they are all independent, I'd like to process them concurrently.  The problem is that each file might use, say, 10 prepared statements.  So now for each file I'm making a new database connection (even though they are pooled), setting up these 10 prepared statements, and then closing them and the connection down for each file; so this is happening thousands and thousands of times instead of just a single time before.

I haven't actually done any timings but I'm curious if this use of connections and prepared statements is the best way?  Is it really expensive to set up these prepared statements over and over again?  Is there a better way to do this?  I've read that you don't want to share connections between threads but maybe there's a better solution I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

> if this use of connections and prepared statements is the best way? Is it really expensive to set up these prepared statements over and over again?

You can reuse the connections and prepared statements over and over again for sure.  You do not have to re-create them and for the connections, you certainly do not have to reconnect to the database server every time.  You should be using a database connection pool at the very least.  Also, you cannot not use a prepared statement in multiple threads at the same time.  And I also think that for most database connections, you cannot use the same connection in different threads.

That said, it might make sense to do some profiler runs because threading database code typically provides minimal speed increase because you are often limited by the database server IO and *not* by the threads.  This may not be true if you are mixing queries and inserts and transactions.  You might get some concurrency if you are making a remote connection to a database.

To improve the speed of your database operations, consider turing off auto-commit before a large number of transactions or otherwise batching up your requests if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but maybe I wasn't clear. Each file is processed by a new thread and since I can't share connections over threads each thread needs a new connection. And since prepared statements are attached to connections, I have to recreate the prepared statements for each file I process.  And the time I'm spending isn't so much in the database transactions but in the file parsing (they are quite large).  That said, I agree about the batch processing, but I already do that.

Comment: Oh cool.  You are mostly there then.  You can certainly reuse the prepared statement in each thread though if you are doing the same statement over and over.  Even if you switch files, you can use the same statement @rjcarr.

Comment: Don't start a new thread for each file. Use a thread pool (to avoid creating threads again and again), and a connection pool (to avoid creating connections again and again). That said, if multiple threads are reading files from the same disk, it could very well be slower than using a single thread. Consider having one thread to read the files, and several to parse and update the database.

Comment: @JBNizet: Thanks, I'm using connection and thread pools.  As I tried to state, since I can't share connections with threads, I need to recreate the prepared statement for each thread (and thus, each file I process) and this is the problem I'm trying to solve.  You might be right and I'm going about this the right way and to think about using concurrency in a different way.

Comment: Creating a prepared statement is probably not what costs the most. And there's a good chance the connection pool or the native connection or the driver caches them anyway. See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_statement_pooling for examplefor how to cache statements with C3P0. I wouldn't try to cache statements by myself. Your way of using JDBC is how everybody uses it in a typical Java EE environment.

Comment: Or the database activity itself.  Again, turning off auto-commit does wonders for large insert blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use C3P0 API Check it http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/

Enhanced performance is the purpose of Connection and Statement pooling especially if you are acquiring an unpooled Connection for each client access, this is the major goal of the c3p0 library.

This part is taken from C3P0 Doc about threads and heavy load:

> numHelperThreads and maxAdministrativeTaskTime help to configure the behavior of DataSource thread pools. By default, each DataSource has only three associated helper threads. If performance seems to drag under heavy load, or if you observe via JMX or direct inspection of a PooledDataSource, that the number of "pending tasks" is usually greater than zero, try increasing numHelperThreads. maxAdministrativeTaskTime may be useful for users experiencing tasks that hang indefinitely and "APPARENT DEADLOCK" messages.

In addition, I recommend you user `Executor` and `ExecutorService` in (java.util.concurrent) to pool your threads.

Look like the following:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int numberOfThreadsNeeded);
// Executor executor =Executors.newCachedThreadPool(); // Or this one

executor.execute(runnable);
.
.
.
etc
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but maybe I didn't make this clear enough.  I'm using both connection and thread pooling already.  This isn't my problem.  My problem is having to rebuild the prepared statements every time I process a file because each file gets a new thread and each thread requires a new connection (again, even if the connection is pooled.)